# $|\mu(A \cap B) − \mu(A \cap C)| \leq \mu(B \triangle C)$ provided $\mu(A)<+\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a finitely additive measure and suppose that $A, B$ and $C$
are sets in the domain of $\mu$ with $\mu(A)$ finite.
Show that
$$|\mu(A \cap B) − \mu(A \cap C)| \leq \mu(B\triangle C)$$
where $B \triangle C = (B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B)$ is called the symmetric difference of $B$ and $C$.

Comment: (Measures are *always* countably additive, hence always finitely additive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A\cap (B\cap C)) + \mu(A\cap (B-C))
$$
and
$$
\mu(A\cap C)=\mu(A\cap (B\cap C)) + \mu(A\cap (C-B)).
$$
Since $\mu(A)<\infty$, we get 
$$\mu(A\cap B)-\mu(A\cap C)=\mu(A\cap (B-C))-\mu(A\cap (C-B)).$$ 
So 
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\mu(A\cap B)-\mu(A\cap C)| &= |\mu(A\cap (B-C))-\mu(A\cap (C-B))|\\
&\le \mu(A\cap (B-C))+\mu(A\cap (C-B)) \\
&=\mu (A\cap (B\triangle C)) \le \mu(B\triangle C)
\end{aligned}
$$